# What is Proper way related this Query in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to implement a Quiz type application where the Question is of two type.

1) MCQ type which have 1 Question and 4 Options (One of this is answer).

2) It will display two images and tap the difference between original and dummy image (May be its has 4 (or any random count) difference).

That both type questions display randomly. Now the problem is in type 2 question, both Images is load dynamically then **how can I set the `UIButton` on dummy images where the differences between original and dummy images, if the image will display dynamically?** because the images are different in each time.

May I set pixel in `database` with the `ImageId` for where is the difference between that two images?
**or** It has the other alternate solution rather then this?

If related any documentation or any link then please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2 Methods

- You can setup the button above the imageviews(using the same frame)
  using button type custom not adding an image you will have a blank
  buttonand use its touchevent for the purpose
- Using gesture recognizer you can set up touch event on the imageviews itself

Use [Asyncimageview](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) to load images asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Bittu, for each image, you should store :

1. Image ID
2. Difference in the image (location / pixel) & map it to Image-ID

So, when you dynamically display an image, fetch the differences (which are stored in the Database, which is mapped to its image ID) & use it to check if the user has tapped/touched on the differences correctly.

Comment: i know that concept but i need alternate solution for it b'coz images will changes in database on every month